# Convert birthdate to age with DATEDIF function

Tags: excel

In Excel I calculate age **"Year"** by DATEDIF function.

example: Born:15/08/1988

formula applied: `=DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"Y")`

result is "30-01-1900"

expected result should be "30"

[[image: image showing result]]

Comment: Your formula works for me.  The cell `A1` is probably not in the date format, or has some other problem.

Comment: Tim i have applied date format to the cell to even though the result is same

Comment: Highlight cell `A1` and press `CTRL + 1`.  What format is that cell?

Comment: the cell is in dd-mm-yyyy format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is perfectly fine but cells B1 and B2 are in date format. Select both cells, right-click, go to "Format Cells" and change the format to "Number".

Comment: Kaiser thank you I was able to change the format and got the expected result.